# F# how to search and count occurences up untill a point?

Tags: f#

I made a data structure to represent a house maze. The way it works is that a path can either lead to the a dead end where there is either a cake, ice cream or oven, or it can lead to an intersection that is either Left, Right, Double (left and right paths) or Triple (Left, Middle and Right paths).

Here are the types and the layout of the house

```
type path =
|End of string
|Double of path * path
|Triple of path * path * path
|Left of path
|Right of path

let GingerbreadHouse = Triple(
                        Double( Double(End("*"), End("X")), Left(Right(End("X"))) ),     
                        Left( Double(End("*") , Left( Double(End("X") , Right(End("O"))))))  ,    
                        Left( Triple(Right(End("X")) , Double( Double(End("*") , End("X")) , End("X")) , Double(End("X") , Right(End("*"))) )) 
                        )
```

Now what I am trying to do is count the number of cakes reached before reaching the oven while follwoing the right most path first.

I first tried doing it with a simple helper function that keeps track of the count and when it reaches the oven it will just retrun the count. However I hit a wall as I cant exactly return the dead ends in this way.

```
let YummyKids house =
let rec helper house count =
    match t with
    |Left(p) -> helper p count
    |Right(p) -> helper p
    |Double(lp,rp) -> helper count + helper count
    |Triple(lp, fp, rp) -> helper rp count + helper mp count + helper lp count
    |End(treat) when treat = "*" -> helper ??? count
    |End(treat) when treat = "X" -> helper ??? (count+1)
    |End(treat) when treat = "O" -> count     
helper house 0
```

So my second attempt I thought I would stick with the normal backwards recursion method however I hit another wall as I have no clue on how to actually end the whole thing when it reaches oven.

```
let YummyKids house =
match t with
|Left(p) -> YummyKids p
|Right(p) -> YummyKids p
|Double(lp,rp) -> YummyKids rp + YummyKids lp
|Triple(lp, fp, rp) -> YummyKids rp + YummyKids mp + YummyKids lp
|End(treat) when treat = "*" -> 0
|End(treat) when treat = "X" -> 1
|End(treat) when treat = "O" -> //???
```

This would work if were looking to count the number of cakes in the entire maze but I only want to count up until a certain point such that when it reaches the oven. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of your recursive function needs to indicate how many cakes you found so far, but also whether the process has already reached an oven and should therefore terminate.

Then you can implement the branching so that it continues to the other branches if an oven has not been found yet (adding the number of cakes), but returns immediately when an oven is found in one branch - before looking into the other branches.

In the following, the return type is `int * bool` where the `int` represents a number of cakes and `bool` is `true` when we hit an oven. The interesting case is the handling of `Double`:

```
let rec YummyKids path =
  match path with
  | Left(p) -> YummyKids p
  | Right(p) -> YummyKids p
  | Double(lp,rp) -> 
      let cakes, finished = YummyKids rp
      if finished then cakes, finished else
        let moreCakes, finished = YummyKids lp
        cakes + moreCakes, finished
  | End(treat) when treat = "*" -> 0, false
  | End(treat) when treat = "X" -> 1, false
  | End(treat) when treat = "O" -> 0, true
```

In `Double`, we first look into the right branch and if we found an oven, we return the number of cakes so far. If `finished = false`, we look into the right branch and add the cakes.

I left the `Triple` case unimplemented, but you should be able to complete that fairly easily following the same pattern as in the `Double` case.

Answer (score 3):

Tomas has answered your question. I'd just like to point out a couple of possible optimizations:

- A single argument function expression immediately followed by matches on the argument `let func arg = match arg with...` can be replaced by a pattern matching function, `let func = function...`
- You can match against literals, e.g. `"X"`, `"O"`, `true`, so that the guarded pattern matching rule with the keyword `when` may be avoided
- The `Triple` case can be constructed from two `Double` cases
- Multiple cases binding to the same pattern can be combined into an *or* pattern that specifies the right hand expression only once
- To make the pattern matches complete and avoid the warning, specify 
  a wildcard pattern `_`
- A single argument case can be given without parentheses

Thus we may also arrive at this:

```
let rec YummyKids = function
| Double(lp,rp) ->
    match YummyKids rp with
    | _, true as result -> result
    | cakes, _ ->
        let moreCakes, finished = YummyKids lp
        cakes + moreCakes, finished
| Triple(lp,mp,rp) -> YummyKids (Double(Double(rp,mp),lp))
| Left p | Right p -> YummyKids p
| End "X" -> 1, false
| End "O" -> 0, true
| End _ -> 0, false
```

Comment: Or even better, change "X", "O" and "*" to union type cases to make the match type safe and exhaustive.